# Unable to boot Ubuntu 14.04 suddenly

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, boot-repair, reboot

I was doing a lot of system installs such as GL, cmake etc. I finished installing and I am unable to reboot Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I ran the hardware diagnostics and no errors were found. It starts and you see the violet screen and it just hangs. 
I did try to access the GRUB menu by pushing the shift button but it does not seem to appear. Instead it goes straight to hardware diagnostics. 
I have a Dell Vostro 3800 desktop and no Windows is installed on this machine. It is a pure Linux desktop.

I saw this boot repair software - https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Do I need to write this to a CD and then try to boot from CD ROM drive ?

Comment: make a live usb from another pc and try fixing grub

Comment: @BrijRajKishore - is the data safe ?

Comment: yes, unless you delete it.

Comment: @BrijRajKishore - after creating a live usb of Ubuntu 14.04 I insert the usb into the Ubuntu desktop and then what ?

Comment: Check whether the storage is not full. It become unable to start when your root partition/ directory gets full

Answer (score 2):

Note: It is mainly for grub rescue for the systems having multiple OS but it worked for me. It Needs an active Internet Connection
Run Commands :

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo update-grub
>
> sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair

launch Boot-Repair from either :

the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)

or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal

Then click the "Recommended repair" button.
When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OS.

If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.
Hope It Helps.

Source - : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mFEg4Hbw2kk

Comment: I get a no boot device available . It looks like a hardware issue

Comment: What is the error can you send it with screen shot or just click it with cell phone and send

Comment: Page Not Found Link

Comment: it says boot device not available. SATA 1 available SATA not avaialb.e Press F1 to boot

Comment: This might be helpful. Please ensure in bios that your hard drive is detected . See : http://www.tomsguide.com/forum/56993-35-what-boot-device-mean